# Create a customized android component with a ViewPager inside

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentmanager

Here is the layout of my application.

[image]

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.test.myapp.ContainerView
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

container_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

ViewPagerAdapter.java:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mFragmentManager = fm;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new PageFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java:
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

ContainerView.java:

```
public class ContainerView extends LinearLayout {

    public ContainerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        // TODO: This is very ugly, how to fix this
        ActionBarActivity activity = (ActionBarActivity) context;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.container_view, this, true);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)root.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

As you know, the ViewPagerAdapter need FragmentManager. That's why I have this line in my ContainerView.java so that I can get FragmentManager through activity.getSupportFragmentManager():

```
ActionBarActivity activity = (ActionBarActivity) context;
```

This works but it's very ugly. Is there any better way? Thanks.

Comment: Either change your `PagerAdapter` implementation to use views instead of fragments, or manage it from the activity. Not only is casting the view's context to `Activity` an 'ugly' solution, but it's also unreliable. It's not guaranteed the the context will always be the `Activity` object itself, it could be a theme wrapper etc.

Comment: I thought ViewPager always work with Fragment.

Comment: `PagerAdapter` is a very generic interface that can work with both fragments and views. See the following code for a simple view implementation without recycling: https://code.google.com/p/viewpagerexample/source/browse/trunk/AwesomePager/src/com/geekyouup/paug/awesomepager/AwesomePagerActivity.java

Comment: But how do I pass data to PagerAdapter? When I add parameter in constructor. It warns me there is no default constructor?

Comment: As shown in my sample link, you need to extend the base `PagerAdapter` class, not `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.